# Get the FIRST CHAR of matched substring

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, pattern-matching

I'm trying to insert into link (href) a matched substring but without the first char who are a '#'.

Infact I would like wrapp #hashtag with a link, that's working very good but when I using $& pattern, it return me the matched on the whole. I want take off the '#' in my href.

```
.replace(/#[a-z0-1A-Z]+/g, '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=**$&**">$&</a>');
```

It's possible to exclude the first char ?

Answer (score 0):

Use group capture. And the capture will be at `$1`

```
.replace(/#([a-z0-1A-Z]+)/g, '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=**$1**">$&</a>');
```

Comment: Oh infact is pretty simple :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.replace(/#([a-z0-1A-Z]+)/g, '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=$1">$&</a>');
```

Placing part of the regex inside parentheses (called group capturing) makes that part accessible with `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and so on for each set of parentheses.

Comment: Thank's you for your tip, its clear in my mind now !

Comment: No problem ;) feel free to mark this answer as the solution so that the question gets solved

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do dis, I haven't eleven points. So once I have it, I'll push your answer.